# What is C's World?

Tags: code-geass

So throughout my viewing of Code Geass (both seasons) I was under the impression that the people shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHAuU.jpg) were an alien or ancient civilization that lived on Jupiter and were the source of the Geass powers that had been passed down to certain people on Earth.

Now I went to the wiki and started to read all these things about C's World and collective unconsciousness and the crazy plan by Charles and Marianne, which I previously assumed was just a plan to make everyone obey and have no free will.  What is the collective unconsciousness (I read Jung and it doesn't seem to relate)? I'm really interested in what that all means and what does this have to do with people's souls and the Code Geass universe's take on life after death and the like.  I don't really understand any of this, somehow I slept through it all.  Also, what was the guarantee that it would succeed? Is the World of C a product of an ancient civilization or is it a mechanism of the Code Geass universe?

So can anyone fill me in?  Any official writings about this or explanations?

Comment: I don't recall Jupiter having anything to do with it...

Comment: @senshin when Lelouch commands "God" it's Jupiter in the sky, we can tell because that tower thing that appears when Ragnarok activates is going into the [Great Red Spot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Jupiter), [here's an image of it](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20080902063008/codegeass/images/9/98/Sword_of_Akasha.JPG)

Comment: Well, I missed something in the series XD

Answer (score 4):

There's not too much information on C's World (World of C) or the imagery used in connection to it. It hasn't been officially explained so until a new canon Code Geass series is released (R3, a canon prequel like Jet Black Renya) the only information we have will come from the series and interpretations on what isn't fully explained.

What information there is all seems to point to how C's world is the "collective human unconsciousness" which is the source of the individual identities for all humans. Charles plan was to kill this so that everyone became a single identity (thus removing one of the main reason wars start) by using the Sword of Akasha, a temple-like structure which Charles refereed to as a "weapon" which was built by someone else as Britannia (particular Charles) only found it.

C's world is connected to both the living and the dead as when C.C shoots Mao she says

> I'll see you again in C's World

Now we know that C.C's wish

> was to be free of her immortality to be allowed to die

So her line assumes that when her wish is granted she would see Mao.

There's a Theory that C's World may be one of Jupiter's Moons or Jupiter itself as when the characters are at the Sword of Akasha and in the visions Lelouch sees we keep seeing Jupiter. However we can only assume that this planet is Jupiter because it looks like it. It should be noted that the times we see C's world is when the Sword of Akasha comes into play.

C's World also seems to be deeply connected to Geass as entry to it could only be done by/with the help of someone with Geass (Contractee or Code Bearer) as Suzaku is only brought to the sword by Charles or C.C. When Lelouch receives his Contract for C.C we keep seeing the same imagery involving Jupiter, the Sword of Akasha, and the Geass People.

> Also, what was the guarantee that it would succeed?

It's implied that the collective human unconsciousness wanted Charles to succeed because it would have ended war since not once did it try and stop Charles or V.V but Lelouch influenced this to continue the march of time indicating the world would be stagnate and trapped in the past.

My own theory is that the Code made Charles untouchable as to activate Ragnarok originally required 2 Codes. (However after Lelouch saves C.C before Ragnarok is activated Charles is still able to activate it). Whoever built the Sword first probably knew that what happened to Charles and Marianne would happen to them so made it that the Code was required as well. While Marianne could have been killed at any time doing so would have done little to stop it so as long as one collaborator had the Code the plan would in some way succeed. Of course this relies on the fact that Lelouch's second sigil is a result of him obtaining Charles Code and that the Code can't be destroyed (thus why the Code Bearer who C.C got her code from said she had tricked C.C and forced the Code onto her).

At the current time C's World and the imagery used in connection to it hasn't been officially explained so until a new canon Code Geass series is released (R3, a canon prequel like Jet Black Renya) we won't have too much information to go by.

Comment: So it does seem like the soul goes somewhere permanent and not reborn, etc.  It stills seems like C's World might be the world of an old civilization.  Otherwise, how does someone build the Swords and put in a failsafe like you mention.  You call them the Geass people, so I wonder if that lends to another humanoid species too.  I realize that's just your theory.  Just too little information like you said.  Kind of wish they had put more information out there on seemingly something pretty important.

Comment: I edited  your answer for grammar / readability - if I've changed the meaning of something, feel free to edit stuff back in.

Answer (score -2):

Its basically the universal consciousness of all beings.  Individuality is born from there and returned to there, and the combination of everyone's consciousness constituting "God". Very similar to principles of many eastern religions like Hinduism/Buddhism or philosophies like Omega Point or Consciousness Singularity.  The movie Avatar also has something very similar to this. The Na'vi's follow a God called Eywa.  Eywa was their world's universal consciousness where all the planets creatures memories/experiences returned to a central planetary neutral network which can be tapped into by future generations and contributed by future generations. Eywa in turn contributes to the shaping events on the planet. Sorry for the avatar seg-way but figured that was the easiest way to grasp it other than to read up on eastern philosophies.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question - how does this apply to the specific case of Code Geass (and could you back up your interpretation somehow)?

Comment: Did you read his question?? He was asking about collective consciousness.  This response contributes to the concept of collective consciousness and what it is.  It was already established in the show that is what C's world is.  Rewatch the episode where lelouch kills his parents. Also from the wikia:  
"It is later revealed that they are a collective subconsciousness of all humans beings metempsychosed into the World of C, which is visually similar to Jupiter." http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Gods

Comment: @Quikstryke the [Universal Mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_mind) is a bit different from [unconscious mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscious_mind), the "[collective unconscious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_unconscious)," coined by Jung, is part of this). The conscious, the unconscious, and the Universal Mind can either work with or against each other, they are by themselves separate and refer to different things.

Comment: While the wikia says unconscious mind that is actually not what the episode alludes to.  It's talking more about God/universal consciousness as any impact on world of C can also impact the past, future, present and the physical world.  Lelouch killed his parents by casting a command on God that erased them.

Comment: @Quikstryke If you believe that is is the case, please provide some specific in-series references for support, so people can better understand your point of view.